# Who is an Academic Associate?

Tags: university, titles, india

I've recently shifted my career to teaching at University, and I am quite not familiar with the post I am assigned, from the answers what I have read for `entry-level` Assitant Professor and Associate Professor.

I am not familiar with what `entry-level` means. I have completed my Masters and I am going to enroll in Ph.D. next year.

I am also unfamiliar with the term `Academic Associate`, I know my roles and responsibilities, but what is the difference between an Academic Associate and Assistant Professor?

Comment: I've never heard this title; it may be specific to a particular country or university system.  Can you state where you are located?

Comment: Probably salary, expectations and the possibility of getting this position permanently.

Comment: @NateEldredge India

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The term Academic Associate may be specific to India or it may be generic. But a reasonable definition might be: [Academic Associate](https://www.iima.ac.in/web/iima/working-for-us/academic-associate). It seems to be something like a post-doc, though not actually requiring a doctorate. But, according to that definition, it isn't really a faculty position, but one for an assistant to a professor. I suggest that if you want a career you want to look beyond that.

*Entry level* probably means different things in different places. I would hope that it always means entry into an actual career and not just a dead-end job. Thus Assistant Professor (in the US) is entry level, in my view, but adjunct instructor is not, since the latter has little future. An assistant professorship normally requires a doctorate, though there are some exceptions at smaller institutions. But an assistant professor is a regular faculty position with normal faculty requirements: teaching, research, service.

An associate professor nearly always requires a doctorate and a period of probation to earn, normally seven years as an assistant professor if in the US. At the end of the seven years you either get promoted to associate professor or are required to leave. The necessary activities of a probationary faculty member are dependent on the nature of the college or university. For most it is heavily research oriented, but in teaching college the research requirement may be only nominal rather than fundamental. (Again, this is a US perspective and some of it may apply to India, or not.)

But for a career, even as an educator rather than a researcher, you are well advised to earn a doctorate. It will take time and effort, but it gives you options that you won't have otherwise.

Comment: Thank you, Buffy, for your answer it helped me to understand the true nature of my job.